# Selecting multiple sub elements at once

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to write a Stylish style to remove the black background of avatars on a forum I frequent (they put a black background so transparencies are black instead of white so stand out from the forum, which I dislike).

By copying the selector with the Chrome inspect tool I have isolated the needed argument to this

```
#mainpostcontent > table > tbody > tr > td > table.forumline > tbody > tr:nth-child(XX) > td:nth-child(1) > span > table > tbody > tr > td {
    background: none !important;
}
```

Where the XX above is a number. Since the numbering changes whether a user has an avatar or not, I have to saturate the style with about 200 individial lines like so

```
#mainpostcontent > table > tbody > tr > td > table.forumline > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1) > span > table > tbody > tr > td {
    background: none !important;
}
#mainpostcontent > table > tbody > tr > td > table.forumline > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(1) > span > table > tbody > tr > td {
    background: none !important;
}
#mainpostcontent > table > tbody > tr > td > table.forumline > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(1) > span > table > tbody > tr > td {
    background: none !important;
}
```

and so on.

Is there a way I can select all of these with a single selector or is it a limitation of CSS that prevents me wildcarding the first tr:nth-child(2) entry?

Edit: I can't find the accept answer button, this was the answer:
"Could you just remove the nth-child argument of > tr:nth-child(3) > so that it becomes > tr >? – S. Walker"

Comment: Could you just remove the `nth-child` argument of `> tr:nth-child(3) >` so that it becomes `> tr >`?

Comment: If not, https://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/

Comment: You can select the first 5 by using `tr:nth-child(-n+5)`

Comment: @S.Walker That did the trick. Thank you magic internet knowlege mermaid.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a more concise means of selecting the relevant elements, via a class-name or attribute-selector? If you could give us an example of the representative HTML you'd probably - *possibly* - receive answers that aren't quite so verbose or potentially fragile.

Comment: The selector you get from Chrome inspector is often way too specific.

You could easily narrow it down to 
#mainpostcontent table table.forumline table td {background:none;}

Answer (score 0):

it makes more sense to add a class or id to the element for which you want to alter the styles. anyway upload your html for better understanding of the problem